# Storing complex object on Datastore with Pickle, any faster alternatives?

Tags: google-app-engine, pickle

To store a complex object to Datastore i'm currently using this approach:

```
class PickleProperty(db.Property): 
  data_type = db.Blob
  def get_value_for_datastore(self, model_instance):
    value = self.__get__(model_instance, model_instance.__class__)
    if value is not None:
      return db.Blob(pickle.dumps(value))
  def make_value_from_datastore(self, value):
    if value is not None:
      return pickle.loads(str(value))

class ComplexModel(db.Model):
      data = PickleProperty()
```

As you know, Google App Engine does not have the more efficient cPickle module; this results in a very slow operation.

Any better strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs says that `model_to_protobuf` wants a `Model` instance, and if your object already is a `Model` you could just as well make a `ReferenceProperty` pointing to that object directly. I'd suggest you first benchmark pickling with decently realistic data to find out exactly *how* slow pickling/unpickling is. It might not be *too* slow, but it might be good to actually know that before committing to work-intensive fixes, premature optimization being evil and all that (as you probably know..).

But if it actually is slow I'd suggest you try to model the objects that needs serializing in a less capable format (and hence probably faster), for example `JSON` (which would be practical, since you already have `JSON` capabilities in app engine present (import it as  `django.utils.simplejson`).

If it's possible to serialize the objects as `Model` instances I suggest you do that. If you don't know all attributes until runtime, there's always `Expando` models.

Comment: looking here http://inkdroid.org/journal/2008/10/24/json-vs-pickle/ django simplejson seems slower than pickle.

Comment: Interesting! Shows the benefits of benchmarking very well. The simplejson version in the article uses C extensions, though. What the article doesn't benchmark is the newest simplejson without C extensions (C extensions never work in GAE) vs pure Python pickle. But as he posts his benchmarks, that should be a reasonably easy exercise, I suppose.